# How to recognize text regions using histogram?

Tags: python, opencv, histogram

I have a sample image which looks like this:

[image]

There could be one or more horizontal lines that separate text sections. I am looking to get 4 chunks of text which looks like:

[image]

The horizontal lines could be close to the text and the external rectangle is not always there.

I have tried the following
- Threshold
- Erode & Dilate
- FindContours

Since the horizontal line is close to the text, there is no clean way to erode and dilate to get the text above and below the line. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt depending on closeness of the line to the text.

I read that using histograms the horizontal line can be recognized and the text chunks identified always consistently. Any pointers on how this can be done?

Comment: Dilation + [XYCut](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35603061/5008845) should work pretty good. I don't have a Python implementation for that, sorry ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detect hougLines -> Black Out the Lines -> Dialate .

## Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np;

im = cv2.imread("im.png")

im_gray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(im_gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

edges = cv2.Canny(im_gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
minLineLength = 100
maxLineGap = 100
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(thresh,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0),5)


kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)

thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel,iterations = 10)





_,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
minArea=5000 #nothing 
for cnt in contours:
    area=cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if(area>minArea):
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        cv2.drawContours(im,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imshow("thresh", im)
cv2.imwrite('so_result.jpg',im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I changed it a bit to work with other examples. I used boundingRect instead of minAreaRect. One problem which still exists is that I want to read the text in the way the human would read it. But looping through the contours does not maintain that order. Any thoughts?

Comment: Getting an generalized algorithm to that will be tough . One basic approach you can follow is to divide the page into certain zones then you can start with contours belonging to specific zones .

Comment: Is there a way to identify the zones based on the horizontal lines identified by HoughLinesP and if there are no horizontal lines, then the whole column?

Comment: In the image you provided , lines detected won't provide much details in getting the sequence of the contours :/ . . try out different ways

Comment: @Arijit, is there a research paper describing the algorithm you shared? To dig more into the rationale behind the algorithm, and its limitations, future work, etc.