# Detecting text blocks in images using opencv c#

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, xamarin, emgucv

Hello I want to extract text-blocks from images and pass it to ocr for better accuracy. I have been searching on internet but not able to find suitable example for this. I am very new to this concept can anyone please help me out on the same?

[image]

[image]

This is what I want to achieve. 
Note I am using EMGUCV for opencv and ocr. 
I want to scan receipt mostly.
If you can help with that it would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split text lines in scanned document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981144/split-text-lines-in-scanned-document)

Comment: Also look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35603061/5008845)

Answer (score 0):

Is your text always in the same location? If yes, you will have the location of the region of interest.

```
//Create the rectangle
cv::Rect roi(0, 0, 500, 500);
//Create the cv::Mat with the ROI you need
cv::Mat imageRoi = image(roi)
```

Then you can send to the ocr this images

Comment: Hi No it wont be at exact location. I want to scan receipts using ocr.

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: This may help you:
[link1](http://www.danvk.org/2015/01/07/finding-blocks-of-text-in-an-image-using-python-opencv-and-numpy.html)
[link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506105/extracting-text-opencv)

Comment: I have already looked into those link. Since I am new. I cannot port that code for c#. Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can threshold your image into a binary image. After that you can use the morphologic operation "DILATE" (repeatedly) do join the letters. When the letters are joined us the "findContours()" function to extract the contour and the bounding boy of it.