# Crop borders of an image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I need to crop the borders of my image in my OpenCV program. As i need to run a contour detection code to read out the text. The issue is that who ever intelligent enough answered my question didn't run the code themselves. 
The border might not be visible but I shared the binary image so you smarties know that theres a border. That border isn't allowing my contour detection code to go inside the image and fetch Text. Understood??

The image is as given below:
[image]

the original image is below:
[image]

Can anyone suggest a function? Thanks in advance.
The contour detection code was picked from here: 
[detect text contours in image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600015/detect-text-contours-in-image?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: what have you tried so far? do you have the rect you want to crop?

Comment: Please provide the original input image.

Comment: are you familiar with www.google.com?

Comment: That image does NOT have any borders... so which borders you want to crop? if you need to crop the image to your liking you can find several questions in StackOverflow about it...

Answer (score 1):

Next time please use google. There are a lot of solutions out there...

```
cv::Mat image;
int marginSize = 5; // Some value defining the thinkness
cv::Rect roi;
roi.x = marginSize;
roi.y = marginSize;
roi.width = img.size().width - (marginSize * 2);
roi.height = img.size().height - (marginSize * 2);

cv::Mat crop = img(roi);
```